# Theme Transition Z-Index in Windows 8

Tags: xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I've got theme transitions (entrance and content with a set offset) on elements which overlap. The issue is as theme transitions are bought to the front of the page the elements which are animated unreliably overlap each other causing a nasty transition when it is returned to the correct z-index.

It doesn't seem to matter how the elements are structured in the visual tree or the z-index applied to the element, the issue still occurs.

Any help very much appreciated - Ideally I want to avoid writing storyboards though, I'm happy with the entrance/content transition in this scenario!

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar problem myself. Here are some things you can try:

1. make sure the "correct" z-order observed at the end of the animation is indeed correct. Putting some label on your items should make that clear if the items have the z-order you intended
2. make sure the items are are added to the control according to their z-order. In case you use binding make sure the items you add to the collection are arranged by their z-index
3. in case you are using PrepareContainerForItemOverride make sure the logic around your binding is correct

Hope it helps,
Mihai

Answer (score 1):

I decided simular problems with:
Position:   Relative;
Transition: All... (All includes Z-Index)
I made Z-Index:4 and for "HOVERed" elements Z-Index:2000.

Comment: This question is related to XAML, not HTML/CSS